# Trailing slash issues with my .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

So I want to make the trailing slash on my server work, id like users to be able to goto both example/oreo and example/oreo/

So far this is what my .htaccess looks like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

So that the trailing slash gets excluded from the capture group, and you can backreference that in both your condition and target.

Comment: It's still giving me a 404 error when i goto a url with a trailing slash :/